# How to fix "out of memory error" in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting an "out of memory" error in my excel vba. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code below.
Thanks

```
Sub Get_Apps()
Dim MixDesigns As Workbook, MasterWb As Workbook

Set MixDesigns = ThisWorkbook
Dim fromPath As String
fromPath = Sheets("Introduction").Range("C30")
Set MasterWb = Workbooks.Open(fromPath)

MixDesigns.Sheets("data for lists").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A100").ClearContents
MasterWb.Sheets("Elements").Range("I9:I58").Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A100").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
MasterWb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`. It looks that Excel cannot `understand` how to paste 50 cells in a range of 100...

Comment: Exactly where is the error?  Does your "data for lists" sheet have any event handlers?

Comment: thanks both, i think i worked it out.. the MasterWb which is opened via this macro in order to copy values from it has its own macro which auto runs when the wb is open.. so I think opening it in MixDesigns via this macro is causing the other macro to run. I've gotten around this by using a go-between workbook for copying and pasting between MixDesigns and MasterWb, which seems to have solved the problem